# download pdf from webservice (developing a webapplication) Any other alternative?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, apache-cordova

I'm developing a cross platform app using cordova. I use intel XDK as a simulator. I want to download a pdf file from webservice and open it once it gets downloaded.

I have used the following code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhr.open("GET", mapusaurl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',auth);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";    
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var link=document.createElement('a');
        link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download="mapusa" + new Date() + ".pdf";
        link.click();
        window.open(link.download);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

As far as Chrome is concerned it downloads the pdf and then I can open it. For intel XDK when I open the respective page a dilaog pops up where I'm asked the location to save the file and at the same time I get the following error

`Cannot GET /mapusaThu%20Jan%2018%202018%2012:05:40%20GMT+0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time).pdf`

That's probably because it's trying to open the pdf before it has downloaded (it shows up even before I click the save button)

Is there a way to get around this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think better way to handle this is to use [cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file). Write your blob to file and then read. This will work for actual devices.

Comment: @Ashish so there's no need to chage the code right?

Comment: btw I'm getting the following error
Error: Version of installed plugin: "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" does not satisfy dependency plugin requirement "cordova-plugin-file@^5.0.0". Try --force to use installed plugin as dependency.

Comment: No there is not need to change the code. After download you can just use blob to write and read using plugin. You can install 5.x version using `npm install cordova-plugin-file@5.0.0 --save`

Comment: can you help me with the blob thing? where should the blob code be written config file??  I'm new to this

Comment: @Ashish  the blob code??

Comment: I am not sure if I can setup some app for you based on cordova, but [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#create-a-temporary-file) will hep you here. Once you got the response from API, just write the blob to temporary file, and read after that.